# Javascript / meteor android return objects to templates

Tags: javascript, android, meteor, callback

I have the following piece of code in my meteor app

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Meteor.startup(function(){

    var onSuccess = function(acceleration){
      alert( acceleration);
    };

    var onError = function(acceleration){
      return "error";
    }

    var options = { frequency: 3000 };  // Update every 3 seconds

    var getAcc = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(onSuccess, onError, options);

  });
}
```

What that does is retrieve the android phones accelerometer data every 3 seconds, and on a successful poll it will show the object in an alert. This works fine.

However, I don't want this polling code to be in the startup function. I want to have more control over when this is executed

I have a template where I want to display the accelerometer values. I changed the `onSuccess` method in the code above to return the object instead of alerting (the rest of the startup code is the same):

```
var onSuccess = function(acceleration){
      return acceleration;
    };
```

My template looks like this:

```
Template.rawData.helpers({
    acc: function(){
      alert(getAcc);
      return getAcc;
    }
  });
```

What I'm expecting to happen is for the accelerometer data to be stored in `getAcc` in the startup function, but then to return it through `acc` to my webpage. This does not seem to happen. The `alert` in the template doesn't occur either

Is there a way to access these cordova plugins from outside of the startup function? Am I just incorrectly returning the objects between the startup and template sections?

I guess my other overarching question is this: I'm not sure how to display those accelerometer values through a template if theyre gathered in the startup function, and not from a template helper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the template update reactively when the data changes. To do that set up a [reactive variable](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/reactivevar_pkg) that gets updated by the callback. First, install the package:

```
meteor add reactive-var
```

Then, when the template is created, create the reactive variable and start watching the callbacks:

```
Template.rawData.onCreated(function() {
   self = this;
   self.rawValue = new ReactiveVar();
   self.accWatchID = navigator.accelerometer.watchAcceleration(
      function(acc) { self.rawValue.set(acc); }, function() {}, { frequency: 3000 }
   );
});
```

Your template helper can then return the value of the reactive variable, and your template will be updated whenever it changes:

```
Template.rawData.helpers({
   acc: function() {
      return Template.instance().rawValue.get();
    }
 });
```

(Note that in your original code, since the alert wasn't being called, there must be a problem in your template. Does it have the right name?)

Finally, you should stop the callback when the template is destroyed:

```
Template.rawData.onDestroyed(function() {
   navigator.accelerometer.clearWatch(this.accWatchID);
});
```

Note that I've just typed that code here without testing it. You may need to fine tune it a little if it doesn't work straight away.