# Meteor accelerometer plugin

Tags: meteor

Is there a way to access the accelerometer from an app made by Meteor?

In order to access the camera I added a plugin to my project using the command: `meteor add mdg:camera` I'm looking for something similar for the accelerometer.

An example of how to use the accelerometer would be great, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197555/javascript-meteor-android-return-objects-to-templates) for examples of how to use the accelerometer in meteor.

Note that the question is not a duplicate, just a question that includes use of the accelerometer.

Comment: Do you know what plugin the person in that question is using, and how to install it?

Comment: @Phrosen No, sorry. Here is a Github library for accelerometer in Cordova, but Meteor can use the Cordova packages: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device-motion. It includes documentation.